# Impulse resolution not separating objects

Tags: c#, physics, collision

When a collision occurs between two objects in the project I'm working on, I run the following code:

```
Vector2 relativeVelocity = entity.Velocity - this.Velocity;
Vector2 normal = Vector2.Normalize (relativeVelocity);
float normalVelocity = Vector2.Dot (relativeVelocity, normal);
float restitution = Math.Min(this.Restitution, entity.Restitution);

float impulseScalar = -(1 + restitution) * normalVelocity;
impulseScalar /= this.InverseMass + entity.InverseMass;

Vector2 impulse = normal * impulseScalar;
this.Velocity -= this.InverseMass * impulse;
entity.Velocity += entity.InverseMass * impulse;
```

While it does get close, the impulse is not quite enough to separate the two colliding objects and results in the stuck object being unable to move in any direction. Something must be slightly off, but what? Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: So, make the impulse bigger. Remember that floating point arithmetic is not exact.

Comment: Could you give us an example? The simpler the better.

Comment: The impulse shouldn't be responsible for separating the two objects. You will want to compute the penetration vector, and separate the objects by simply changing their positions, using that vector. The impulse should then be used to set the two objects on their new trajectories. If you are interested in seeing a fully realized solution, just say, and I'll put up an answer.